# Tracking Changes

Tags: ssrs, condition, change-tracking

I have an SSRS report with hierarchies for the company and their contact info. As these hierarchies change overtime, is there a way to track what has changed since the last run(run on a weekly basis)? Is there a way to compare and highlight changes?